# Does Teleric RadGridView support remote paging in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, telerik

I am wondering if the Teleric [gridview](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-overview.html) supports paging by fetching the data from a web service each time the page index is changed.

I have tried to enable paging in the gridview but it seems that the gridview applies pagination on the data that has been set as the datasource.

Is there a way to achieve remote paging in the Teleric gridview, since I don't want all the data in memory at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can not fetch records equal to page size of grid and apply paging, that would be like *I've total of 40 records and i want to fetch only 10 records and do paging also with page size 10*. Hence what you are trying to achieve is contrary to each other and is not possible by using paging of gridview as it requires a datasource and you must fetch all records to bind it, then why to call a webservice to fetch only that number of number of records equal to your page size when you have all the records with you. Hope you got the point.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. But, please note that I am talking about the gridview in teleric winforms.

Comment: I think I have already mentioned in my question that I don't want to load all the data in memory.

Comment: yeah to which i posted my answer and told you that its not  possible by giving an example too.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, RadGridView does not support server side paging. However, you can use the virtual mode feature and pull the data on your own (as per your request) and populate the cells. More information on this feature is available here: [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-virtual-mode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Paging emulation with RadGridView for WinForms is possible, especially if we take full advantage of LINQ. 
This approach, however, is seldom used for WinForms applications, although there are cases when paging in WinForms grids is needed as well, especially when there are million records in the database (literally).
and also You can access the RadGridView.GridViewElement.PagingPanelElement only programmatically for more changes.[PagingPanelElement](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/paging/paging-panel)

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/emulating-paging-with-radgridview-for-winforms-and-linq-with-1-million-records

The important part of the code is the BindGrid method that does the actual loading of the data:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
 this.radGridView1.GridElement.BeginUpdate();

 IQueryable queryable = new DataClasses1DataContext().MyTables.AsQueryable();

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(where))
    {
        queryable = queryable.Where(where);
    }

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))
    {
        queryable = queryable.OrderBy(orderBy);
    }

    radGridView1.DataSource = queryable.Skip(currentPageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

 this.radGridView1.GridElement.EndUpdate(true);

    EnableDisablePager();
}
```